# Simple Android Drag and Drop Not working

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-linearlayout

[image]

Hi, as you can see in the screenshot above, I have two linearlayout objects, the left sidebar is one, and the lighter bigger area with the tablet icon in the center is the other one.

All I want is to be able to drag a copy of any of the 2 ImageVies on the left side bar over to the linearlayout object.

The problem comes when I try dropping the image disappears, I looked into the z-index problem but I don't think that is what is is. I would appreciate any help with this.

**MainActivity.java**

Note: I know I can create a myTouchListener class instead of implementing the interface every time I set a touch listener, but didn't for the sake of simplicity since I am a beginner android developer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView arduinoLogo;
ImageView piLogo;
LinearLayout mainDrop;

String msg;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    arduinoLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arduinoLogo);
    piLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.piLogo);
    mainDrop = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainDrop);

    mainDrop.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction()){
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: {
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    viewgroup.removeView(view);
                    LinearLayout containView = (LinearLayout) v;

                    containView.addView(view);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    break;

                }
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    arduinoLogo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData clipdata = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(arduinoLogo);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
                    v.startDragAndDrop(clipdata, shadowBuilder, arduinoLogo, 0);
                }
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    piLogo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData clipdata = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(arduinoLogo);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
                    v.startDragAndDrop(clipdata, shadowBuilder, arduinoLogo, 0);
                }
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.proviz.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainSidebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:background="#eee"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/arduinoLogo"
                android:src="@drawable/arduinologo"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/piLogo"
                android:layout_below="@id/arduinoLogo"
                android:src="@drawable/pilogo"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainDrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!--android:background="#00aaaa"-->>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/thistablet"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```